# Understanding HTTP Session security mechanism in JHipster

Tags: csrf, jhipster

I am trying to figure out how the JHipster uses HTTP session for securing application and logging the user.
So far I’ve managed to understand the flow like this:

1) on landing page home.component sends request to `api/account`
with session cookies (if there are ones)

if there is a valid session >> uses credentials from stored cookies and then login the user

if no >> backend server responds HTTP 401 and sends XSRF cookie in response

As I understand responsible for this is Spring Security

2) when there was no acitve session we can fill the login form and log in
    that sends request to `api/authentication` (XSRF cookie from step 1 required)

if all ok >> responds HTTP 200 and sends new XSRF cookie

if no >> HTTP 403 and sends new XSRF cookie

3) when step 2 is successful then frontend sends credentials from login form to `api/account`

one more time Spring Security checks XSRF cookie value (from step 2 this time)

if all ok >> business logic for log in the user is invoked

But in all these steps  we need to intercept the cookies sent by backend and send them back to be able to pass through CSRF protection.
 Which part of JHipster project is responsible for that?
 Does it use webpack/browsersync or there is some Angular code created by JHipster which I am missing?

**EDIT**
My problem appeared when I've made a lot of changes to generated project as I want to use custom templates/styling and the services generated by JHipster. I've linked the templates with jhipster services.

When I try to log in the user I get in spring console output like this:
`Forbidden: Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'`
 From previuos request to `api/authentication` I get response with
`Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=a129cb47-ec96-47be-aaae-69f90848c466; path=/`
in browser network.

So it sets the cookie with wrong name I guess. I've change the cookie name manually in browser to: `X-XSRF-TOKEN` and resent the request. The new error looks like  this:
`Forbidden: Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.`

I don't understand the flow enough so I can't spot where is the problem. Maybe I've messed up and maybe there is some code generated by JHipster which is responsible for that. There are some classes in JHipster Angular frontend like StateStorageService. Do they take part in my problem or they are irrelevant to that issue?

Comment: Cookies are sent automatically by browser, there's no client code needed here. Or maybe I did not understand your question.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I've updated my question with some clarification, hope it is clearer now

Comment: Sorry I can't help as I have no idea what you did differently from JHipster's generated code.

Comment: Maybe I chose bad approach. Do you @GaëlMarziou think that it is better to copy templates, scripts, css and so on to JHipster project? (of course with adjustments so it will be compatible with JHispter services etc.)

One more question. Does JHipster somehow configure proxy or sth that Angular can modify/set cookies even the backend and frontend run on different ports? I've read that even the services run on my machine on localhost, different ports are counted as different domains. And that's why Angular is not able to modify different domain cookie.

Comment: What do you mean by "Angular is not able to modify different domain cookie", cookies can't be changed by javascript code especially when httpOnly is true (see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly#What_is_HttpOnly.3F ) JHipster webpack server configuration already setup a proxy for you in dev, see `proxy.conf.json` and `webpack/webpack.dev.js` files in your project, you can add more config to it if you want to proxy to another server than your JHipster backend

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while connecting a mobile app to the backend of spring boot. So basically angular has a method under the core functionalities called interceptors. Under the interceptors the response is gather and X-XSRF-TOKEN is captured and updated in Browser Cookie or in my case Ionic Local Storage as Cookie.